# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis on LISTAGG function error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, listagg

I know this question has been asked many times. But going by the articles which are already answered I am not able to find solution for the query which I am developing.

So the query goes as below:-

```
select  A.COLUMN1,
        LISTAGG(C.COLUMN2,'/' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.COLUMN2) AS RANK
from 
        TABLE1 A,
        TABLE2 B,
        TABLE3 C
where 
        A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN1
        AND A.COLUMN1 = C.COLUMN2
GROUP BY
        A.COLUMN1 , C.COLUMN2;
```

I am getting below error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 34
```

But I can see no parenthesis which is missing. Can someone suggest what might be wrong in the above query?

EDIT-3:

Details of Oracle version:-

Output of

`select * from v$version;`
[image]

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Hi @acroniks, please explain to me what is this in your code: "where CONDITIONS FOR JOINING TABLES;"

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have used proper `JOIN` conditions in actual query. I have modified the query so that I can post it publically. :-)

Comment: @acroniks why couldn't you post it with proper `join` syntax?

Comment: Well show the original one because with this query we have another error

Comment: @VBoka I have replaced the joining conditions with this line "where CONDITIONS FOR JOINING TABLES;"

Comment: @acroniks we can not help you in this way: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d4a21e4f9f71f87f46312b9ce8ae73a4 in this link you can see your code (with error), your code without where clause(with error), and then the last one is the code with corrected error... How can we help when we can not simulate your error?

Comment: @acroniks in your updated code you are missing AND keyword ??? Again not the same error ... Here is the link and check it out: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3d9d1c35c01292013b8f4e7b5d178a39

Comment: You've tagged as 12c, but 12cR1 or 12cR2? The overflow clause is only available from 12cR2, and you'd get this error in 12cR1 (or 11gR2). Also `RANK` is a function name so I'd avoid that for a column alias.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have added Oracle version details. I am not sure it is 12cR1 or 12cR2.

Comment: @acroniks - 12.1.0.2 is 12cR1, so you can't use that clause. Are you expecting aggregated values longer than varchar2 can handle?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes exactly. I am expecting aggregated values longer than varchar2 can handle

Comment: Then XMLAgg is probably your best bet. I've closed as a duplicate of a question that shows how to do that.